# Where is the data for the default Google Android launcher located for 7.1/8.0/8.1?

Tags: android, android-launcher

**For Android 7.1 as well as Android 8.0/8.1, where is the data for the Google default launcher and its icons (links) located?**

Edit: I'm speaking of the default Android launcher that comes on a Google-branded phone (in particular the Nexus 6 7.1.1 or Pixel 2 8.0/8.1 default factory launcher).

I'm particularly interested in comparing launcher link data for a link I added in 7.1 that got migrated to 8.1, but which cannot be re-created same as that original directly *from* 8.1 (the link was originally added via Chrome). Root is available.

Comment: What is "the Google default launcher"? There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed home screen implementations, across the ~10,000 Android device models.

Comment: I updated the question. It's the standard bundled launcher from Google for Google phones made and sold by Google with the default Android experience for their phones. There are two Google phone lines of particular interest as stated above.

Comment: "It's the standard launcher from Google for Google phones made and sold by Google with the default Android AOSP experience" -- there hasn't been a device with that description in many years. Neither the Nexus 6 nor the Pixel 2 have "the default Android AOSP experience". Among other things, they each use proprietary home screen implementations.

Comment: References to AOSP were already removed, lest they confuse anyone else. The factory image of Android 7.1.1 on the Nexus 6 comes with the Google's default launcher. Likewise Android 8.0/8.1 on the Pixel 2. Those are the only Google factory default launchers for those phones that exist, and are as noted in the question the particular two launcher versions of interest (three, if 8.1's is substantially different in where it stores its config and layout data).

Answer (score 0):

I've determined via other sources that the default launcher for the Pixel 2 is `com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher`.

The data of interest is within `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/databases`

In `launcher.db`, the `favorites` table appears to contain the data of interest.